# Setter methods do not work whereas Getter methods work fine

Tags: error-handling, getter-setter, setter

The error is always that the dino cannot be converted into type string 
   however im struggling to understand why the compiler would think of trying to 
   converting dino into ints or strings from the first method

```
public static void Tyrannosaurus() 
{
    String DinoName = Name();
    Dinosaur Tyrannosaurus = new Dinosaur();
    Tyrannosaurus.name = DinoName;
    Tyrannosaurus = setDiet(Tyrannosaurus, DinoDiet[0]);
    Tyrannosaurus = setHP(Tyrannosaurus, 100);
    Tyrannosaurus = setDamage(Tyrannosaurus, 200);
    DaysLoop(DinoName);
    return;
}
```

Here is the first getter method being used for the Dinosaur record and Tyrannosaurus instance above

```
public static String getName (Dinosaur dino)
{
     return Tyrannosaurus.name;
}
public static String getDiet (Dinosaur dino)
{
 return Tyrannosaurus.diet;
}
public static int getHP (Dinosaur dino)
{
     return dino.HP; 
}

public static int getDamage (Dinosaur dino)
{
     return dino.damage; 
}
```

setter method which does not work is done from here, I do see in other java setters people use this. but I havent quite grasped that concept yet

```
public static String setDiet (Dinosaur dino, String TyranDiet)
{
    dino.diet = TyranDiet;
    return dino;
}
public static int setHP (Dinosaur dino, int TyranHP)
{
    dino.HP = TyranHP;
    return dino;
}
public static int setDamage (Dinosaur dino, int TyranDamage)
{
   dino.damage = TyranDamage;
   return dino; 
}
```

//////////////////////////////////

Comment: you need to move declartion of Dinosaur Tyrannosaurus into class level. otherwise it couldn't be called by any other methods without Tyrannosaurus()

Comment: And Please don't write class like this, don't use this kind of static setters and getters methods.

Answer (score 0):

You return dino as string and dino as an int in below methods.

```
public static String setDiet (Dinosaur dino, String TyranDiet);
public static int setHP (Dinosaur dino, int TyranHP);
public static int setDamage (Dinosaur dino, int TyranDamage);
```

that's why its pops error like that

basically setters not returns anything. remove return and re-write code like this

```
public static void setDiet (Dinosaur dino, String TyranDiet)
{
    dino.diet = TyranDiet;
}
public static void setHP (Dinosaur dino, int TyranHP)
{
    dino.HP = TyranHP;
}
public static void setDamage (Dinosaur dino, int TyranDamage)
{
   dino.damage = TyranDamage;
}
```